# Symfony Annotations what does @return float|int mean

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, return-type

I understand that

> `@return int`

means the function is going to return an integer and that

> `@return float`

It will return a float value.

But what about

> `@return float|int`

Does this mean it will return float or int ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not symfony, it is just the php documentation.

```
@return float|int
```

return either a `float` or an `int`

http://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/return.html

It's important to note that it is just documentation, you can have a function with bad return documentation if you don't maintain it:

```
/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getAge()
{
  return 'I am a string'
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I only mentioned Symfony because it makes heavy use of Annotations for it's own use, so I thought it relevant to mention.

Comment: @PrestonDocks No problem, I just wanted it to be clear :]